# How to type an arbitrary glyph in the font tables of msam and msbm?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I thought that the font encoding of msam is `U`. When I TeXed `\fontfamily{msam}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont\char"39` I got `9` which is clearly from `cmr` (encoding: `OT1`). Does anyone know how to TeX that symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The family names are msa and msb:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{msa}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont\char"39
\fontfamily{msb}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont\char"39

\end{document}
```